# assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI, Version=xxxx, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxx' could not be loaded

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, deployment, reference, assemblies

Q:

I face the following problem only when i tried my web site from the production server.

locally every thing goes okay.

> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2011.2.712.35,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4' could not be loaded.
>
> ```
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
> To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
> Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
> To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
> ```

**Note:** If i paste the `Telerik dll` in the bin folder .the problem is fixed.

but i wanna to know the reason , and any way to fix this problem without copy and paste the `dll` in the bin folder.

Comment: Did you hosted on Shared hosting service ?

Comment: if i understood u , yes.

Comment: Telerik.Web.UI is large in size and sometime it cause to application pool to recycle on Shared hosting.

Comment: then how to fix this problem ,please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question well, try to include this file as a reference inside your project, so every time you make a deployment, it will by default include it inside the bin folder.

this is to avoid copying the file every time you deploy.

let me know if this fits your problem or not.

**Update**: as per your comment, kindly check my attached image, and follow my instructions below.
[image]

1- Open "references" and select your "telerik" Dll

2- Right click over it and select "Properties", or simply press "F4".

3- check that the option says "**Copy Local**" is **True**, if not,then change it.

4- make another deployment, now it suppose to copy your desired Dll in the bin folder.

5- draw a big smile, the problem is gone!!. :)

let me know if this address your problem correctly, thanks

Comment: I do this already and i have a reference .but when i go to the bin folder ,there 's no `telerik dll` file.

Answer (score 1):

The host server would have to install the Telerik ASP.NET AJAX libraries into the GAC if you wanted to publish your site without including the Telerik DLL. If you own the server or have dedicated access to it, this is no problem. Just run the Telerik installer on the production server and you're all set (it will add the appropriate assemblies to the GAC).

If you do not own the server, such as the scenario where you are using a shared hosting service, you will need to include the Telerik DLL in the bin folder. The reason being, shared hosts will likely not allow you to install assemblies into the GAC, and even if they did, Telerik's licensing probably doesn't cover this.

To make sure your build always has the Telerik DLL, go to your solution, References, select the Telerik reference, and change it to Copy Local = true

Comment: hmmm,did this method (the last one) has a performance drawback problem?

Comment: There is no performance difference if an assembly is shared via the GAC, or referenced privately in the bin. The purpose of the GAC is so that an assembly installed once and used by multiple applications, without having to copy it locally for each and every application using it. Having it installed on the production server would be nice, if you can manage it, because you'd be able to shave 14 MB off your deployment (last time I checked the Telerik ASP.NET AJAX assembly was 14+ MB, bleh).

Comment: "Telerik.Web.UI is large in size and sometime it cause to application pool to recycle on Shared hosting. " by  dotnetstep

Comment: Yes, that assembly is large. I can't speak to any particular issues regarding Telerik and app pool recycling. However, neither of those facts strike me as having any relevance in GAC vs private deployment. There is no performance or stability improvement in either deployment method.